# how to put each @ContentChildren into individual div which is generated by using *ngFor

Tags: angular

I tried to make some tab-like components here, but I got some question.

here is the usage of my components:

```
<app-ui-tab001-frame>
    <app-ui-tab001-item [tabTitle]="'titleA'">contentA</app-ui-tab001-item>
    <app-ui-tab001-item [tabTitle]="'titleB'">contentB</app-ui-tab001-item>
</app-ui-tab001-frame>
```

the html of  "app-ui-tab001-frame" is just like :

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let tab of tabArray.toArray()">

         <ng-content></ng-content>

  </li>
</ui>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let tab of tabArray.toArray()">
     <div>
         **I want to put each @ContentChildren here**
         **tried {{tab.elemRef.nativeElement.innerHTML}} here but not working**
     </div>
  </li>
</ui>
```

the html of "app-ui-tab001-item" is just like:

```
<div class="tab-pane" *ngIf="isActive">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

the ts of  "app-ui-tab001-frame" is just like :

```
export class UiTab001FrameComponent implements OnInit,AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(UiTab001ItemComponent) tabArray : QueryList<UiTab001ItemComponent>;

  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() {

  }
  _checkWindowWidth(){

  }

  ngAfterContentInit(){

    console.log(this.tabArray.toArray());

  }

}
```

the ts of "app-ui-tab001-item" is just like:

```
export class UiTab001ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() isActive :boolean = false;
  @Input() tabTitle :string = null;
  public elemRef :ElementRef<any>;
  constructor(private elem :ElementRef<any>) { 
    this.elemRef = this.elem;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and what I want is to put every "app-ui-tab001-item" component into individual div which is generated by *ngFor(is it possible?), but I don't know how to make it work.

I tried to use elementRef in the constructor() function of "app-ui-tab001-item" component, and inject "{{tab.elemRef.nativeElement.innerHTML}} into those divs, but it didn't worked in the way I want .
actually I am new to Angular : ( Just need someone to point out my mistake

Comment: It can be achieved easily using Angular Content Projection. Go through this video to learn more about it - https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/content-projection/
Another good article explaining the same is - https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Just wrap the `ng-content` of the item in `ng-template` and use `ngTemplateOutlet` to render the item in list component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-item',
  template: `
  <ng-template #content>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-template>
  `
})
export class ItemComponent {
    @ViewChild('content', { static: true }) content: TemplateRef<void>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-list',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let tab of tabArray">
      <div>
         <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="tab.content"></ng-template>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  `
})
export class ListComponent {
    @ContentChildren(ItemComponent) tabArray : QueryList<ItemComponent>;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nukgpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It works :D
but there seem still some problem, guess I have to find the way fix it.
thank you bro !